# show display name after signUp

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter firebase `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function with the `displayName` update.
display name prints normally at the moment of fb user creation.
After signup `MainPage` loads with the users email and `displayName`. But `displayName` returns null value error. If I delete `displayName` from the `MainPage` - all works fine.
If I reload app, it works fine.
When I login, it works fine.
It can't pass the `displayName` at the moment of signup only.
Where I am wrong?

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final googleSingIn = GoogleSignIn();

  UserModel? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return UserModel(
      user.displayName,
      user.uid,
      user.email,
    );
  }

  Stream<UserModel?>? get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

 
  Future<UserModel?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    String name,
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final userCred = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      auth.User? firebaseUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        await firebaseUser.updateDisplayName(name);
        await firebaseUser.reload();
        firebaseUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      }
       print('FIREBASE USER IS $firebaseUser');
      

      return _userFromFirebase(firebaseUser);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually the solution is very simple if you think a little bit.
As all this is through the firebase auth, at the main page loading I just grab the firebase user with its display name that is saved in FB both for GoogleSignIn and createUserWithEmailAndPassword (required at registration)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final String firebaseUser =
        _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.displayName ?? 'Unknown user';
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class were to extend either `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`, then all you'd have to do is to pass the data (`displayName`) between the screens.

***This is not an answer but a suggestion:***

1. You should try changing the `ChangeNotifier` to a `StatefulWidget`
   and pass the data between screens...
2. You could also setup an
   Authentication class that will hold all these Future methods so that
   these calls can be reusable in your code. With this method, all you have to do is to call the specific function and give its required parameters.